# Duration of animation based on user drag event

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-animation

I now work on SpinTheBottle app, my bottle is spinning, but I want the speed of the spinning will be based on the users onTouch event, and I want it to be stopped at random positions, I can drag the bottle but the animation always starts from the center and after 2 rotations stops at the same position as in the beginning.

What am I doing wrong?

my code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    final float xc = bottle.getWidth() / 2;
    final float yc = bottle.getHeight() / 2;

    final float x = event.getX();
    final float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            bottle.clearAnimation();
            mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2( x - xc, yc - y));
            break;

        }case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle;
            mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
            animate(mPrevAngle, mCurrAngle, 0);
            System.out.println(mCurrAngle);
            break;

        }case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle = 0;

            float toDegrees = new Random().nextFloat() * Integer.MAX_VALUE % 360;
            final Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mainanim);

            animRotate.setDuration(1000);
            animRotate.setRepeatCount(1);
            animRotate.setFillAfter(true);


            bottle.startAnimation(animRotate);

            break;
        }case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{


        }
    }

    return true;
}


private void animate(double fromDegrees, double toDegrees, long durationMillis){
    final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation((float) fromDegrees, (float) toDegrees,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(durationMillis);
    rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    bottle.startAnimation(rotate);
    System.out.println(mCurrAngle);
}
```

anim layout:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">

<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:drawable="@drawable/campari"
    android:duration="2500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Many things. F.e. You are implementing your animation in ACTION_MOVE, random numbers in MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL , plus you have an extra xml RotateAnimation, which you don't need.

I would go a very different approach here. For general animations check out [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) and its methods, its the easiest way to animate Views. Heres something to start with :

Minimal example for spinning your bottle connected to a Touch Event :

```
int start = 1000;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            start = 1000;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            start = start + 250;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Random random = new Random();
            int toDegrees = random.nextInt(start);
            int duration = random.nextInt(start + 1000);

            bottle.animate()
                .rotation(toDegrees)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                .setDuration(duration);

            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This has a minimum duration/rotation of start = 1000; :

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        start = 1000;
        break;
```

, and the longer you move around on the screen the bigger start gets and with it the duration/rotation :

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        start = start + 250;
        break;
```

Then when you let go of the screen create Random numbers :

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        Random random = new Random();
        int toDegrees = random.nextInt(start);
        int duration = random.nextInt(start + 1000);
```

where it will generate a random number between 0 and 'start' .

This is ViewPropertyAnimator rotating your bottle with decreasing speed and your generated random rotation/duration:

```
bottle.animate()
   .rotation(toDegrees)
   .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
   .setDuration(duration);
```

Thats basically all you need, and just to give you an idea of an alternative, and in my opinion, better approach for future Animations.